# Aptana FTP plugin notification like SVN or Git

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ftp, aptana

Can I configure Aptana's FTP connections in such a way that it shows some type of symbols like * or + for those files which are not yet uploaded? Just like it shows for files when not committed to Git or SVN repositories. If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

no!

but you could do this (see highlighted region 3)
[image]

Comment: Thankx Alex. I know we can do that sync automatically. But just would like to know if there is any kind of notification process. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Yes we could do it that way. But I don't want to keep uploading stuff. Once after committing my changes to repo, I wanted to FTP them to our external server. In which case, I guess Automatic sync is not possible.